# Python Tools for Visual Studio - generate exe

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

is PTVS capable of generating exe file from a Visual Studio Python project or do I have to do it manually using e.g. py2exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no this is not possible currently.

As you can see on their [github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki#features-in-depth) (it's an open source project) it's also not listed as one of the features that it offers.

I looked around for a bit for 3rd party extensions and on nuget, but found nothing.

So it looks like you'll have to do it manually for now. You *could* implement the feature yourself I guess, by contributing to the project ;-). Or [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen) to discuss it.